# Linux terminal is not same in Android studio and normal terminal window

Tags: linux, git, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I use Elementary os (Ubuntu based) and I have configured terminal to simplify the usage of git. I used the instructions given at Udacity's **How to use git and GitHub**.

This is in my terminal when I opened by <kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

[image: Terminal when opened normally]

This in android studio terminal.

[image: This is in android studio]

But I want the same terminal in android studio too.

Comment: My Android studio terminal reflects the changes I've made to my configuration. How did you configure your shell (e.g. by modifying `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`)?

Comment: It worked perfectly at the beginning. But after I have made certain changes like changing Theme from IntelliJ Ide to Dracula and I have added some editor themes like Sublime text etc..                                                                                         I don't know when it has changed but it is changed. Is that a problem?                 I have also tried to reconfigure terminal from Android studio. But No Use....